# Error Establishing Connection if there are multiple users using the site

Tags: mysql, database

We have a ASP.NET application deployed internally and it is being used by almost 500 users. There are instances that when a lot of users are using the site, there's an error connection.

We have tried several options like pooling, optimizing our code, but we still don't know if this has something to do with the server. Right now, we are using shared hosting (dedicated 1.5 gb ram). Do you think upgrading the server will resolve this issue?

Also, is database computation dependent on ram and # of cores?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer below supplied by @michael is a good starting point with regards to looking at max connections.  The other thing I would ask is are you using persistant connections, thus keeping connections open for more than the (ideally) milliseconds that the application actually needs to access the database? In most cases, just because you have 500 people using an application at once, doesn't mean to should have 500 DB connections open, as typically the DB connection is only needed for a small percentage of the time that a user is actually interacting with the application.

Comment: Continuing my comment above... if the application only spends 5% of the time a user is interacting with the application actually querying the database (probably a high estimate for most applications), then for 500 users, you might only need 25 DB connections on average.